# How do I display a message when I login?

Tags: linux-mint, startup

I am trying to display a message when I log on to **Linux Mint 17.2**. I have tried various methods without success:

1) I created a file `/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "My startup message"
pause
exit
```

I made the file executable and made sure it works from a command line, e.g.

```
bash "/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh"
```

or

```
sh -c "/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh"
```

Then I used Mint's 'Startup Application' feature and added a new entry. I tried:

```
  "/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh"
  bash "/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh"
  sh -c "/home/myusername/Desktop/startup-message.sh"
```

with and without quotes around the path name. In all cases, nothing was displayed and the "pause" was ignored.

Finally, I added a command to copy a file after the pause, and the file was copied. So, it appears that `echo` and `pause` are ignored in a start-up file, presumably because no terminal is open?

2) I then tried adding the message to `/etc/profile`, but the message didn't appear when I logged on.

3) I then tried adding the message to `/etc/motd`, but the message didn't appear when I logged on.

So how can I perform this simple task?

Comment: Are you logging into a terminal or X?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the function of `echo`. `echo` will print to the standard output file descriptor. If you already have a terminal open, that terminal is usually the standard output of the commands/scripts you run within it. By itself, `echo` will not open a terminal.

If you want to display a message on startup, a more "graphical" way would be to use something like `zenity`:

```
zenity --info --text "Hello, world!"
```

If you put that in your startup script, you will see a message box displayed to that effect.

Also, `motd` prints your message for text-based logins (like a login on a virtual terminal or a login via `ssh`) so it's not going to do what you want either.

If you want to specifically open a terminal on startup, you can make your script do something like:

```
xterm -e 'bash -c "echo My startup message;sleep 10"'
```

Comment: Thank you. The "zenity" command does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add this echo into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` ?

More info at [An Explanation of .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile)

> Both the ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile are scripts that might be executed when bash is invoked. The ~/.bashrc file gets executed when you run bash using an **interactive** shell that is not a login shell. The ~/.bash_profile only gets executed during a **login** shell.